# Why isn't "delete" keyword deleting the node?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I have implemented a doubly linked list. The problem is to delete the node with a specific value. For this, I first have to find that value in the list. If it exists I have to delete it setting the rest of the pointers accordingly. I have even tried deleting by using "free" instead of "delete" but that too didn't work in my case. No errors are there in the code but the node doesn't get deleted after execution.
Here goes my code:

```
void remove(i)
{
    node *n= find(i);
    node *prev= n->GetPrev();
    node *next=n->GetNext();

    if(n!=NULL)
    {
        if(prev!=NULL && next!=NULL)
         {
            prev->SetNext(next);
            next->SetPrev(prev);
            delete n;
         }

        else if(prev!=NULL && next==NULL)
         {
            prev->SetNext(NULL);
            delete n;
         }
    }
}
```

P.S I have written code for all the possible cases in the same way.

The **destructor** for this class is written as:

```
~DL()
{
    node *current = head;

    while (current)
    {
        node<T> *next = current->GetNext();
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
    delete head;
    delete tail;
}
```

I have inserted distinct integer values in the list. The insertion works properly. But when I try to delete nodes inserted in the list using a loop, the same node that was previously on the head gets returned showing that it wasn't deleted before. The checkRemove function implements these steps.

```
checkRemove()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        addToHead(i);
    }

while(length>10)
node *temp= returnHead(); 
if (temp != NULL)
            cout<<"Value of head node is "<<temp->returnValue()<<endl;
            remove(temp->returnValue());
}
```

In my case as the values in the list are distinct so they are occurring only once. The print statement prints the "Value of the head node" statement twice only instead of printing values till the length of the list becomes 9.

Comment: How do you know the node is not getting deleted?

Comment: @P.W By compiling it on mingw and printing values of the nodes

Comment: I haven't included the print statements here to minimize the code

Comment: Can you post a minimal example so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you specify a little bit as to what exactly should I provide?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A `delete` calls a possible available destructor for the given class and marks the memory the object occupied as being free. `delete` does not reset the pointer `n` pointed to, so it still points to the same memory address. Accessing that address will be undefined behavior. The behavior in most cases is that you can see the old values until the memory is overwritten in a later stage. What you most likely observe is undefined behavhiour because you access memory that was already freed, but to give you more details a mcve with those prints is required.

Comment: @P.W Have a look

Comment: @t.niese i have added my destructor function in the code above

Comment: This is still not a mcve. A mcve is a code that can be copied as is an will reproduce the problem. Beside that you have a double delete in your code, the first iteration in your destructor would delete `head` because `current` initially points to head. And then after you loop you delete `head` again. `tail` is most likely also a double delete. And as i said before `delete head` will delete the object, but the `head` will still hold the memory address it was pointing to, that's normal behaviour. You have to set the point to e.g. null manually.

Comment: @t.niese making the memory address null didn't solve the problem either. Secondly I cant put up the whole project here

Comment: @user399 No one asked for your whole project but for your list and node implementation.

Comment: A MCVE does **not** mean a the full project. It should be a stripped down version of your `DL` class containing `remove`, `checkRemove`, `addToHead`, `add`, `returnValue`, ... as a complete class, with a `main` function and if that code is run it should reproduce the problem. The `delete head;` at the end of your `while` is undefined behavior as you call `delete` on an already deleted memory address. And if making the memory address null  doe snto change anything then the problem is else where. But without a run able code it is **not** possible to tell where exactly the problem is.

Comment: linked list is better with sentry node https://pastebin.com/DXunz58Q

Answer (score 2):

Besides that what you showed can't be your real code,

> ```
> void remove(i)
> {
>   node *n = find(i);
>   node *prev = n->GetPrev();  // **** crash if n == NULL
>   node *next = n->GetNext();
>
>   if (n != NULL)  // **** is too late, execution will never reach this if n == NULL
>   {
>       if (prev != NULL && next != NULL)
>       {
>           prev->SetNext(next);
>           next->SetPrev(prev);
>           delete n;
>       }
>
>       else if (prev != NULL && next == NULL)
>       {
>           prev->SetNext(NULL);
>           delete n;
>       }
>       // n won't be deleted if both prev and next are nullptr
>   }
> }
> ```

Simpler:

```
void remove(int value)
{
    node *n = find(value);
    if (!n) return;  // nothing to do

    node *prev = n->GetPrev();
    node *next = n->GetNext();

    if (prev) prev->SetNext(next);
    if (next) next->SetPrev(prev);

    delete n;
}
```

Comment: I have taken care of the case when both pointers are null. Didn't include the complete code due to the size.